# Can I change language for one specific app?

Tags: root-access, languages, localization

I run my phone in the English language. However, there is one specific app that does not work properly in English but starts working immediately as soon as I change system language. It is not a bug, just poorly translated.

Can I somehow change the language for one specific app?

My phone is rooted, and I could repack .apk if this would help. BTW I also want to cut access rights of the app.

Comment: The only solutions I know of require the XPosed framework – and haven't been updated recently: [Xposed App Locale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zhangfx.xposed.applocale) and [App locale 2](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.flo354.xposed.applocale). [There are some more](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_settings#group_545) which might include this.

Comment: I am thinking more along the lines of editing apk to cut out the English language. then it will have to resort to native. Or not?

Comment: Not sure if "editing the APK" would be considered on-topic here. Though I think it could work removing the language files, though you'd lose the signature when re-packaging (so no automatic updates, and keeping the data would require some specific Xposed tricks).